# How to edit .bst file to change the order of series name and number?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, linguistics

I'm using `natbib` and `linquiry2` to typeset my bibliography (as you may notice I've already hacked `ed.`
For the following `.bib` entry:

```
@inproceedings{KornfiltPreminger:2015,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Kornfilt, Jaklin and Preminger, Omer},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 9th {W}orkshop on {A}ltaic {F}ormal {L}inguistics ({WAFL} 9)},
    Editor = {Joseph, Andrew and Predolac, Esra},
    Number = {76},
    Pages = {109--120},
    Publisher = {MITWPL},
    Series = {MIT Working Papers in Linguistics},
    Title = {Nominative as \emph{no case at all}: An argument from raising-to-\textsc{acc} in {S}akha},
    Year = {2015}}
```

I got this:

> Kornfilt, Jaklin, and Omer Preminger. 2015. Nominative as no case at all: An argument from raising‑to‑ACC in Sakha. In Proceedings of the 9th Workshop on Altaic Formal Linguistics (WAFL 9), ed. by Andrew Joseph and Esra Predolac, No. 76 in MIT Working Papers in Linguistics, 109–120. Cambridge, MA: MITWPL.

But what I want to get is this:

> Kornfilt, Jaklin, and Omer Preminger. 2015. Nominative as no case at all: An argument from raising‑to‑ACC in Sakha. In Proceedings of the 9th Workshop on Altaic Formal Linguistics (WAFL 9), ed. by Andrew Joseph and Esra Predolac, MIT Working Papers in Linguistics 76, 109–120. Cambridge, MA: MITWPL.

So, how do I edit `linquiry2` to get the desired result? The `format.number.series` part from the `.bst` is as follows:

```
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { bbl.number }
            { bbl.number capitalize }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          bbl.in space.word * series *

        }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

And the `inproceedings`(though I think the problem is not with this part, since number and series is in the same block):

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    %% Was: format.in.ed.booktitle (need different capitalization-- Alexis)
    { format.in.ed.proctitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Comment: The file `linquiry2.bst` does not appear to be distributed with TeXLive. Is available online somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it's available at https://www.ling.upenn.edu/advice/latex/linquiry2.bst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative definition for `format.number.series` that should do what you want could be

```
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { series empty$
        { number field.or.null }
        { series field.or.null
          number empty$
            'skip$
            { number tie.or.space.connect }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

Please do not edit `linquiry2.bst` directly. Only modify a renamed copy (add a few comments about the changes and the current date to the header).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{KornfiltPreminger:2015,
  author    = {Kornfilt, Jaklin and Preminger, Omer},
  title     = {Nominative as \emph{no case at all}: An argument from raising-to-\textsc{acc} in {Sakha}},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 9th Workshop on Altaic Formal Linguistics ({WAFL} 9)},
  editor    = {Joseph, Andrew and Predolac, Esra},
  year      = {2015},
  series    = {MIT Working Papers in Linguistics},
  number    = {76},
  pages     = {109--120},
  publisher = {MITWPL},
  address   = {Cambridge, MA},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{KornfiltPreminger:2015}
\bibliographystyle{linquiry2-series}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Kornfilt, Jaklin, and Omer Preminger. 2015. Nominative as no case at all: An argument from raising-to-acc in Sakha. In Proceedings of the 9th Workshop on Altaic Formal Linguistics (WAFL 9), ed. Andrew Joseph and Esra Predolac, MIT Working Papers in Linguistics 76, 109–120. Cambridge, MA: MITWPL.]

Comment: Thanks! I tried this on a renamed copy but unfortunately the console said it can't open the .bst file.

Comment: @MarcelLyu You need to put the file somewhere BibTeX can find it. The easiest solution for a one off is to put it into the same directory as your main `.tex` file. Do not put the file into the file tree administered by your TeX distribution.